# CircleCi Orb browser tool is failing

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, circleci, circleci-orb

in my `.circleci/config.yml` I have specified this orb: `browser-tools: circleci/browser-tools@1.4.3`. It is failing due to the following error:

```
Installed version of Google Chrome is 116.0.5845.140 
ChromeDriver 116.0.5845.140 will be installed
116.0.5845.140 will be installed
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 
mv: cannot stat 'chromedriver-linux64': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'chromedriver/chromedriver': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver': No such file or directory
/bin/bash: line 194: chromedriver: command not found
Something went wrong; ChromeDriver could not be installed
```

It seems like that the URL is changed where chromedriver is hosted. I updated the browsertools to version 1.4.4 but I still run into the same issue.
Does anyone know how to fix this or has the same issue?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Got the same issue but haven't been able to figure it out yet. Will be following this and post if I figure it out

Comment: See See https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/browser-tools-orb/issues/90

Comment: @TrevorDeVore I also found this and it fixes the issues as long as there is no chromedriver for the latest stable chrome release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix it, change in`.circleci/config.yml`:

```
browser-tools: circleci/browser-tools@1.4.4
...
- browser-tools/install-chrome:
          chrome-version: 116.0.5845.96
```

Answer (score 0):

That works for me but adding replace-existing:

```
  - browser-tools/install-chrome:
            chrome-version: 114.0.5735.90
            replace-existing: true
```